# Command+key problem for the Chrome browser in the Mac OS

Tags: java, selenium

This works for the Firefox browser.

Could please help to understand why this code is not working for the Chrome browser on the Mac OS?

I do not get any error, but actions do not perform.

I have also used `Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a");`. It does not work as well.

**Device:** MacBook Air

**OS:** macOS Catalina / **Version:** 10.15.5

**Browser:** Chrome / **Version:** 83.0.4103.116

```
public class draft2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("PATH");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='firstName']"));
        WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lastName']"));

        firstName.sendKeys("test", Keys.COMMAND, "a");
        firstName.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND, "c");
        lastName.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND, "v");

    }
}
```

Comment: you can do it with Actions class, but what is the use case of it, you can just sendkeys() the first name and last name with the same value, or you can get the attribute value of the first name and sendkeys() it to the last name

Comment: @NorayrSargsyan Thanks for your reply. A use case of it is to verify that able to copy/paste data in the input field, and using sendkey() you verify that any characters are entered in the input. By the way, the Actions class is not working in this case as well.

Answer (score -1):

To open a new tab

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('')")
```

To switch to the newly opened tab

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

To switch back to the original tab

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Hope this answers your question. If it does click on the tick icon

Comment: My problem is related to the Command key action for chrome browser on mac OS. Sorry, but I didn't understand what you meant in your answer. How can **window handles** connect with my issue?